# c++ compile time assert that BASE is base class of EXTENDED and have same memory address

Tags: c++, casting, std

```
struct A
{
};
struct B : A
{
   virtual ~B() {}
};
template<typename BASE, typename EXTENDED>
void ASSERT_BASE_EXTENDED()
{
   static_assert(static_cast<BASE*>((EXTENDED*)256)==(BASE*)256, "error");
}
```

I'm looking for a way to have a compile time assertion to check if BASE class is a base of EXTENDED, and they have the same memory address.

In the above example even though B is based on A, when casted to A it has a different memory address, because the virtual function table pointer is actually the first member of B. But I need a check if A is the first member.

The above works OK but is not compile-time, because I'm getting an error "error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant" when using VS 2017 compiler.

I'm not interested in "std::is_base_of" because that one ignores checking for the same memory address.
Is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You want to use the [_CRTP_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and `static_cast`?

Comment: The CRTP is an interesting concept however the goal is to don't modify existing classes and only adjust the ASSERT_BASE_EXTENDED function.

Answer (score 2):

Memory addresses are a runtime construct. You cannot check them at compile time because at that point they don’t exist. The same is true for the kind of casting you mention. That happens at runtime entirely. You’ll have to replace `static_assert` with a runtime check and error handling, e.g. an `assert()` or an exception.

That’s for the imo common use case. For hard-coded memory addresses like in your example the problem is the cast of those address-ints to pointers. The only valid way to do this is a reinterpret_cast (that’s one of the casts the compiler tries for the C-style cast in your example), because the types *int* and *pointer to T* are completely unrelated. But reinterpret_cast is not allowed at compile time.

Clang’s error message puts it nicely:

```
main.cpp:14:38: note: cast that performs the conversions of a reinterpret_cast is not allowed in a constant expression
    static_assert(static_cast<BASE*>((EXTENDED*)256)==(BASE*)256, "error");
                                     ^
```

Comment: I disagree with you. If you check my code again you will see that I'm creating a pointer to an object from a constant memory address of 256. Also I'm using static_cast which unlike dynamic_cast can perform adjustments to the memory offset by a known to the compiler value. Nothing prevents the compiler to evaluate the entire line at compile time, but it doesn't. These are basically arithmetic operations on known constants at compile time.

Comment: I intuitively took those hard-coded addresses for a simplification for the questions sake. For that case the actual problem are the casts. See the updated answer.

Comment: IMO whatever the compilers could optimize (pre-calculate) - they should. If they would, then it would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Limitation: it works only with classes which has constexpr constructors

```
class Base_A
{
    size_t a;
};

class Base_B
{
    size_t b;
};

class Derived2: public Base_A, public Base_B
{
    size_t x;
};


template<class Derived, class Base>
constexpr bool IsSameAddressCast()
{
    Derived drv; 
    Derived* drv_p = &drv;

    Base* base_p = drv_p;
    void* drv_v = drv_p;
    void* base_v = base_p;
    return (drv_v==base_v);
};

static_assert(IsSameAddressCast<Derived2, Base_A>(), "different address");
static_assert(IsSameAddressCast<Derived2, Base_B>(), "different address");// this assert will triggers
```

Another solution suppose you can access some not static member in base class

```
    class Base_A
    {
    public:
        size_t amember;
    };

    class Base_B
    {
        size_t b;
    };

    class Derived1: public Base_B, public Base_A
    {
        size_t x;
    };

    class Derived2: public Base_A, public Base_B
    {
        size_t x;
    };

    class Derived3: public Base_B
    {
    public:
        size_t amember;
    };

template<class T>
struct Allocator_OffsetOf_ObjData
{
    static const size_t value = (size_t)&(((T*)nullptr)->amember);
};

template<class Derived, class Base>
constexpr bool IsSameAddressCast2()
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value, "not a base class");

    return Allocator_OffsetOf_ObjData<Base>::value == Allocator_OffsetOf_ObjData<Derived>::value;
}

    static_assert(IsSameAddressCast2<Derived1, Base_A>(), "different base address");// triggers assert
    static_assert(IsSameAddressCast2<Derived2, Base_A>(), "different base address");
    static_assert(IsSameAddressCast2<Derived3, Base_A>(), "different base address");// triggers assert
```